# How do resolv.conf and linux DNS work?

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, docker

I had some problems with docker networking (specifically custom DNS proxy setup) and I found out that my resolv.conf was a bit strange:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

  nameserver 172.17.0.1
  nameserver 10.0.0.10
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

So, 3d party custom DNS proxy basically changed the 3rd IP to something like this:

```
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver [proxy-dns-entry-ip]
```

And all my requests to hostnames under this DNS were breaking at `10.0.0.10` with `nslookup`:

```
$ nslookup container1.hostname           

;; Got recursion not available from 172.17.0.1, trying next server
Server:     10.0.0.10
Address:    10.0.0.10#53

** server can't find container1.hostname: NXDOMAIN
```

```
$ nslookup container1.hostname [proxy-dns-entry-ip]

Server:     192.168.144.3
Address:    192.168.144.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   container1.hostname
Address: 192.168.128.3
Name:   container1.hostname
Address: 192.168.128.3
```

I've edited the file and just commented out the first two IP addresses, and the new DNS is working properly, also when this proxy is disabled and the only entry is `127.0.0.53`, the host network is working properly too (like, I can ping google and use my browser), docker and containers are working too.

I'm quite new to networking (especially with Linux). Could someone explain to me what is happening here with these 3 addresses and how it all couples to ubuntu's DNS servers (i mean the ones I define in GUI network settings)?

Comment: So you're asking four separate questions.  One is about how those entries work, one is about how DNS works, the third is what the file does, and the 4th is about how to stop resolvconf from doing its job.  These are four separate *distinct* questions that should probably be asked individually.

Comment: I think they are tightly related to my problem and asking them separately would be a bit 'spammy'

Comment: I updated my question, it's okay now?

Comment: "if yo uget a reply for a lookup on the 2nd it stops there, etc", but the second returns error, why the third one is never used?

Comment: *resolv.conf* is a link to */run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf* and as the header suggest you should not edit the file manually, and should only contain 127.0.0.53... the config is done via systemd

Comment: @Stanislav read my answer.  DNS is "Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, Quarternary, ..." in the lookup process.  First one to give an answer stops the lookup to the subsequent servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer your questions out of order because they're all slightly different, but also because the answers to one will help you understand the answers to another, etc.

**Answer to #2: How DNS Servers Work In Your System, and partial answer to #3 on what resolv.conf does**

When you have multiple DNS servers used in your system, they're queried in order.  So if my resolv.conf has:

```
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 5.6.7.8
nameserver 10.10.1.0
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

...then anything requesting a DNS record on your system will first try 1.2.3.4.  If 1.2.3.4 responds, then that's the end of it (includes SERVFAIL error responses and NXDOMAIN responses, both of which are 'valid replies').  If it times out in a response however, and doesn't return a response, then it tries the next server - 5.6.7.8.  If 5.6.7.8 responds then it stops there.  If it fails to respond, then it continues to try 10.10.1.0.  This continues until one of the servers listed in order gives a response or they all time out.  This is by the design of DNS as "First one to actually reply is the one that we handle"

This is because it goes Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, Quaternary, etc. for the order of lookups.  The first to respond stops the lookup chain.

The last one in your list and in the example list here, 127.0.0.53, goes to your SystemD ResolveD stub which is where the answer to #3 comes in.

**Answer to #3: How is this different than your GUI settings?**

In short, `resolv.conf` is used under the hood to determine your DNS server priority settings.  NORMALLY in 18.04 it will just point to `127.0.0.53` which is your `systemd-resolved` handler.

Your `systemd-resolved` handler will in turn be fed by your Network Manager GUI settings your DNS servers to use for its recursive queries.  This is an example of the settings fed by my GUI settings into `systemd-resolved` on my wifi connection:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
  ....
    Link 2 (wlp59s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.10.1.0
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

What happens is when your system gets a DNS query and hands it to 127.0.0.53, that will check its local DNS cache to see if there's a record already known.  Then if it fails, it queries the DNS Servers specified in the system.  In this case, assuming that my `resolve.conf` is a basic system and looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

... will result in a lookup for `google.com` to go to the local `systemd-resolved` instance and if it doesn't have a cached DNS entry it will then go to 10.10.1.0 with the DNS request from within `resolved`.

However, in your system, the behavior will differ, per answer #2, because your resolv.conf has multiple other revisions in it that will break this process.

**Answer to #1: What're those addresses?**

Someone or Something has altered your resolv.conf system to add those additional addresses.

That was either you or Docker doing it.  10.0.0.10 could be another Docker instance or another Docker listener via dnsmasq or such or some other network on your environment added that.

Unfortunately, we can't give any insight into 10.0.0.10 as that could be anything.  We can ID 172.17.0.1 because you said it's Docker, and 127.0.0.53 because that's SystemD ResolveD.

127.0.0.53 as I stated in the answer to #2 and #3 above is your `systemd-resolved` that is fed your GUI DNS settings.

**Answer to #4: How to make the change permanent?**

Unless you remove the symlink, the file is going to be fed by `resolvconf`.  Unless your `resolvconf` is configured otherwise, it's going to be a symlink.  The only way to make a *permanent change* is to break the symlink and then simply have a static file.  So, to use your Docker DNS and then your system DNS, you'd have a static file for `/etc/resolv.conf` that would have the following:

```
# THIS IS NOT FED BY resolvconf, any changes here are PERMANENT.
nameserver 172.17.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

This would then be a permanent configuration setup until you change it or something sets resolv.conf back to the symlink.

Unfortunately, however, short of removing the symlink and replacing with the static file, there is "no way" to tell `resolvconf` to keep a permanent set of commands here.

There's other much more complex ways, such as having a separately configured DNS server system, but that's way outside the scope of 'normal' and is definitely "a hacky workaround" that you probably don't want to start delving into.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it's really helpful. I think i understand the problem now. Something or someone really inserted the '10.0.0.10' IP address into the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` section. I'm sure this IP is useless and should not be in there, so I removed it from the head file (it seems permanent, because after `resolvconf -u` the resulting symlinked `resolv.conf` doesn't have the IP now). Thanks again.

Comment: @Stanislav Yep, keep in mind anything can edit the head file and that could be added back in.  It could be an *old* Docker deployment or network setup from a docker-compose or something that started up finally, but there's no way to tell that from here.  Glad you like the detailed answer, though, and apologies for answering your four questions out of order, but the flow of question to question was better answered out of order :P

Comment: Np. I also rebooted the system to check that no startup processes change it, so I guess it just was a one time event in the past.